# How do I make cp give an error if a file doesn't exist

Tags: linux, shell

When i type command

```
cp notExistsFile.txt ~/Desktop/
```

its gives an error:  "cp: cannot stat `notExistsFile.txt': No such file or directory"

is "cp command" have any option such that if file doesn not exits it wont give any error , it just skip it.

i am performing this from shell script

Comment: you can redirect the stderror message to /dev/null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always redirect the standard error to `/dev/null`

```
cp notExistsFile.txt ~/Desktop/ 2>/dev/null
```